# If Avraham Already Knew Who Yitzchak’s Wife Would Be Why Not Just Tell Eliezer Which Girl To Go To?

Tags: parashat-chaye-sara, eliezer

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.22.20?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.22.20&lang2=bi) (dibbur hamatchil אחרי הדברים האלה ויוגד וגו׳ of [Bereishit 22:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.22.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) says:

> בשרו הקב״ה שנולדה רבקה בת זוגו

If Hashem already informed Avraham exactly who Yitzchak’s wife would be why not just tell Eliezer straight out who it is and he can go directly to the family and say that she is the chosen one for Yitzchak?  Why send him on a mission and speaking generally to find a wife for Yitzchak, what to do and what not to do, where to go and where not to go.  Avraham explained the possibility of the girl not wanting to come ([Bereishit 24:2-8](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.24?lang=bi&aliyot=0)).  Why did he need to ask Hashem to arrange it so that the girl will be the one who comes to draw water and has the quality of chesed and offers drink to Eliezer and his camels ([see Bereishit 24:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.24.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)-14).  Avraham could have Eliezer just bypass it all and go straight to Rivka.

Comment: He may not have told 'exactly' only that she was born.

Comment: I recall reading that Eliezer wanted his own child to marry Yitzchak. By having him see that a woman does such chesed he would understand WHY this woman is the one that he can agree should marry Yitzchak. Had he just been told "go to this address, ask for Becky" he might have wondered "why her?"

Comment: My answer here- https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/118019/22152 is partially  connected - there was more than just finding him a wife he had to underline to Eliezer his spiritual legacy, inheritance and accountability.